# My Apache 2 installation is showing errors. However, the default php file is showing up fine at localhost on my browser. What's wrong?

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache, ubuntu

- Usage: /etc/init.d/apache2 {start|stop|graceful-stop|restart|reload|force-reload|start-htcacheclean|stop-htcacheclean|status}
  root@computer:~# sudo service apache2 stop

  - Stopping web server apache2
  - The apache2 configtest failed, so we are trying to kill it manually. This is almost certainly suboptimal, so please make sure your system is working as you'd expect now!
    ... waiting                                                             [ OK ]
    root@computer:~# sudo service apache2 restart
    apache2: Syntax error on line 237 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/wordpress: No such file or directory
    Action 'configtest' failed.
    The Apache error log may have more information.
    ...fail!
    root@computer:~#

P.S. Wordpress is in the said directory.

Comment: When in doubt reboot

Comment: Yes, I have rebooted multiple times to no avail.

Comment: Find a default config file for: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and replace its content with the default data, something is wrong

Comment: Yes, after linking it to 000-default in /sites-enabled, it's ok. Many thanks